# Springboot Manual JAR not running properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I developed a REST API endpoint in Springboot which displays a greeting when I access:

```
localhost:8081/hello
```

Feeling confident I export it as a 'fat jar' (standalone app) using

```
mvn clean install
```

Now, the problem is when I access the same '/hello' URL endpoint, I get this:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Oct 23 09:15:15 PST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

What the hell happened?
I made sure I specifed my main class in the pom.xml file.

I am using SpringToolSuite 4 IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the guide by [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot) can help you, I'll summarize and add my own:

1. Make sure to have these dependencies:

   ````
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
      </dependencies>

     <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
       </plugin>
     </plugins> ```
   ````
2. Just to be sure specify your main class like:

   ```
   <start-class>com.microservices.MyMainClass</start-class>
   ```
3. Make sure you are executing
   `'mvn clean install'`
   on the correct directory
4. If you want to package it as 'WAR' file instead, use

   `<packaging> war </packaging>`

inside the "project" properties.